# How do I make sure that all data is going to be the same number when transforming data for training and predicting with sklearn models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, encode, sklearn-pandas

I want to make sure that the data in an incoming data set is the same as the data that the model was trained on. For instance...

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'prediction':['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'features': ['one','two','three']})
```

Once this is transformed it should look like this:

```
>>>df
prediction  features
1           1
2           2
3           3
```

Now I want to make sure that a new set of data...

```
new_df = pd.Dataframe({'prediction':['yellow', 'red', 'green'], 'features': ['three','two','one']})
```

Is going to be transformed to the same as the original DataFrame `df`. Note that I did add something in the `new_df` because the model is going to have to handle that as well. The new dataframe should look something like this...

```
>>>new_df
prediction  features
4           3
1           2
2           1
```

How do I make this happen and how can I inversely transform the data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LabelEncoder` here.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'prediction':['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'features': ['one','two','three']})
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df["prediction"])
oldData = df['prediction'].tolist()
df["prediction"] = le.transform(df["prediction"])
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'prediction':['yellow', 'red', 'green'], 'features': ['three','two','one']})
newData = new_df['prediction'].tolist()
newData = list(set(newData)- set(oldData))
le.classes_ = np.append(le.classes_, newData )
new_df["prediction"] = le.transform(new_df["prediction"])
```

Update

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'prediction':['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'features': ['one','two','three']})
from sklearn import preprocessing
encoderDict = {}
oldData = {}
for col in df.columns:
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(df[col])
    encoderDict[col] = le
    oldData[col] = df[col].tolist()
    df[col] = le.transform(df[col])
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'prediction':['yellow', 'red', 'green'], 'features': ['three','two','one']})
newData = {}
for col in new_df.columns:
    newData[col] = new_df[col].tolist()
    newData[col] = list(set(newData[col])- set(oldData[col]))
    encoderDict[col].classes_ = np.append(encoderDict[col].classes_, newData[col] )
    new_df[col] = encoderDict[col].transform(new_df[col])
```

To inversely transform the data all you have to do is the following.

```
ndf = df.append(new_df).reset_index(drop=True)
for col in ndf:
    print(encoderDict[col].inverse_transform(ndf[col]))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. Could you add the inverse transform to the code as well? I'm going to test it now and if all works fine then I'll mark it as the answer. UPDATE- it didn't work properly. `'red'` and the others of the same value get new class labels. They need to be the same... Also, I'm pretty sure that the entire dataframe needs to be transformed into numbers, otherwise it won't fit the model.

Comment: made the changes, it should work fine now. If you want to run it for whole dataset, then put it in a for loop and change `"prediction"` to the column name needed.

Comment: Can I use `df = df.apply(lambda x: le.transform(x))` or something like that? If I can, can you put that into the code as well?

Comment: you can but you shouldnt. Using a single encoder for full dataset is not a good idea

Comment: Ok, but everything needs to be encoded numerically when training a ML model. What do you suggest I do? I need to make sure that all values remain the same...

Comment: repeat this for all features by creating a loop and a dictionary of encoders to use them in future.

Comment: That makes sense! If you want to update the code to do that I can mark it as an answer. If not that's ok I'll edit it when I figure it out.

Comment: Thank you so much @rajat kabra. I'll test it ASAP and mark it as an answer when I can.